# Shopify Multi-currency is not working for orders in customer account page

Tags: shopify, currency, liquid, shopify-template

I am trying to implement multi-currency in one of my testing store.

Everything works great but in customer's account page where orders are displyed currency is not updating.

The symbol of currency is changed but the price is not updating.

Please check attached screenshot for the reference.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The theme I am using is simple theme from free themes.

Is there any particular reason for that?

Or Do I need to update the liquid code?

Do I missing some steps for multi-currency feature?

Any help will be awesome.

Comment: Have you enable more currency from setting in shopify ?

Comment: Yes, It is working perfectly fine in product as well as collection page.

Comment: only issue with account page ? If yes then discuss with support over skyp call or chat both are free

Comment: Not checkout. Account page. customer account page where all the previous orders displayed. It is not happning in one store. all of the store. Are you facing the same??

Comment: Yes I mean account, No

Comment: Can you please share me details for your store? on milind@getflits.com